# Magento: Getting 500 internal server error when creating invoices

Tags: php, linux, apache, magento, ubuntu

I'm facing a big problem with my current Magento Shop. When I create an invoice through the backend I'm getting an 500 internal server error (after a long loading process). The server logs dont show anything, I looked into `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and theres nothing related. The error didnt show up on my dev machine, but since I moved the shop to our live server it occurs all the time.

What I tried so far:

- Checked the file and folder permissions
- Enabled `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
  Still no errors or logs
- Deleted local.xml and generated a new one
- Increased memory limit
- Increased max execution time
- Cleared cache
- Checked .htaccess file, everything seems fine
- Ran a script to check if everything matches the Magento requirements

This is starting to keep my busy for a couple of days now... and I dont know where to start, because the server doesnt even output an error in the logs. How can I force the server to log the error in the according file?

Do you have any other ideas what I can try to get rid of the error?

Attached also my php.ini file, maybe that helps.

PHP.ini http://pastebin.com/9BWQRHTu

PHP Version and OS: PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.21

Env: Virtual Private Server

Comment: Can you see errors if you load a simple test script that triggers an error or warning?

Comment: yes if I enable Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); and ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the wrong error_log file, as I'm using Plesk the correct error_log file was located in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/statistics/logs/ and not in /var/log/apache2/

The error in there was

```
[Mon Nov 04 14:37:13 2013] [warn] [client xxx] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds, referer
```

This lead me to the fcgid.conf (etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf) where I had to increase the following values:

```
FcgidIdleTimeout 3600
FcgidProcessLifeTime 7200
FcgidMaxProcesses 64
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidConnectTimeout 300
FcgidIOTimeout 180
FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
FcgidIdleScanInterval 10
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Increase `memory_limit` from `128M` to `256M` or `512M`.
2. Clear browser cache and cookies. Do you encounter the same "`500 server error`" in other browser?
3. You said the loading process is long - measure the exact time couple of times and if the time is the same, which is set in php.ini, increase the `max_execution_time`
4. Find why is it taking so long to create an invoice using a debugger - most probably some module you have installed has a problem, like infinite loop, or it might trigger an action, which takes a lot of time, for example, reindexes everything each time. Creating an invoice shouldn't take so long and it is a problem in code - not in server settings probably.

Comment: 1. Tried that, didn't help.
2. No success.
3. I increased the execution time, but unfortunately this didn't help either.
4. I'm trying to setup XDebug for a remote connection at the moment... maybe this brings me a step further to the solution of this issue.